# Deallocate pointer target from a pointer alias in Fortran 90

Tags: pointers, memory-management, fortran

the code

```
program asd

real,pointer        :: a,b,c

allocate(a)
a=2.0
b=>a
c=>a
deallocate(b) !
print *, associated(c,target=a) ! T

end program
```

return T with intel compiler. I conclude that "b" is not a full alias of "a", since I can not deallocate "a" taking "b". 
So my question is: if I construct a pointer with

```
function ptr
  real,pointer   :: var,ptr
  allocate(var)
  ptr=>var
end function
```

It is possible to deallocate var after to call this function?

Thank a lot-

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[The standard](http://j3-fortran.org/doc/2003_Committee_Draft/04-007.pdf) says (section 6.3.3.2):

> ... Deallocating a pointer target causes the pointer association status of
>   any other pointer that is associated with the target or a portion of the target to become undefined.

Further on, in section 16.4.2.1, it says:

> A pointer may have a pointer association status of associated, disassociated, or undefined.

and in note 16.3 it points out that:

> A pointer from a module program unit may be accessible in a subprogram via use association.
>   Such pointers have a lifetime that is greater than targets that are declared in the subprogram,
>   unless such targets are saved. Therefore, if such a pointer is associated with a local target, there is
>   the possibility that when a procedure defined by the subprogram completes execution, the target
>   will cease to exist, leaving the pointer “dangling”. This standard considers such pointers to have
>   an undefined association status. They are neither associated nor disassociated. They shall not be
>   used again in the program until their status has been reestablished. There is no requirement on a
>   processor to be able to detect when a pointer target ceases to exist.

All of that is to say that the result of `.TRUE.` from Intel you are getting is compiler-specific because `c` has an undefined association status, which compilers can report any way they want. If you tried to access `a` through `c`, you would get a memory error (or even if it works, it is undefined and not a guarantee).

Likewise, your example function is just as dangerous because there is no guarantee that `var` will exist when the function returns, meaning the `ptr` function result is again undefined. So again, if you tried to access `var` through the result of `ptr`, you would again get a memory error.

If you want your function to work, it would need to look like:

```
function ptr
  real, pointer, save :: var
  real,pointer   :: ptr
  allocate(var)
  ptr=>var
end function
```

Of course, this begs the ultimate question -- why `ALLOCATE` pointers? It's much safer to use `ALLOCATABLE` for the target and give it the `TARGET` attribute.

Comment: +1 for undefined pointers. A note: not so long ago we encountered here, that allocatable structure components cannot have target attribute.

Comment: A note on _why ALLOCATE pointers_: I believe it's the only way to have   dynamic arrays inside derived data-types up to F90/95.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the perfect answer!! About why I need allocate pointers: I need two list, one that store the data and the other that just point to it. Since in fortran there is templates like in c++, I found more easy the use of pointers for the data inside the nodes and change the status as needed. In that way I avoid to declare two list types and the lot of code lines related.